# Prevent click before JavaScript is loaded

Tags: jquery, preventdefault, document-ready

I've problems with my jQuery function:

```
        /* Vertical Profil Navigation */    
    $(document).ready(function() {
        function ajaxLoading(obj){
            var dataString = obj.attr('href');

            if(obj.attr('rel') != '#default'){
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "profile.php",
                    beforeSend: function() { $("#countrydivcontainer").html('<h2 class="title">Loading</h2><div style="text-align:center;"><img src="images/loader.gif" /></div>'); },
                    data: dataString,
                    success: function(data){
                        $("#countrydivcontainer").html(data);
                    }
                });
            }
        }

        $('.vnav-item.profile').on('click', function(e){
            ajaxLoading($(this));
            e.preventDefault();
        }); 
    });
```

When I load the page and click on a link before the complete site is loaded, the link event isn't prevented and I receive an error. How can I ensure that a click on these links is always prevented event though the site isn't completly loaded?

[Visit site](http://test.blackbeats.fm/index.php?site=profile&id=10904)

Answer (score 0):

Put that JavaScript fragment immediately after the links in question in  tags, and omit the $(document).ready handler

This causes the code to be executed immediately after the link is rendered to the screen

e.g.

```
<a href="..." class="vnav-item profile">Here</a>
<script>
    $('.vnav-item.profile').on('click', function(e){
        ajaxLoading($(this));
        e.preventDefault();
    });
</script>
```

(Of course, jQuery must be included somewhere before this)

Comment: If you have errors in your console, make sure to fix those. `ajaxLoading` will have to be defined before this as well (whcih you were originally doing in your document ready handler. If you're not using HTML5 you need to do `<script type="text/javascript">`. Otherwise I'm not sure what the problem is, look at the error messages and post them here